# Configuring PiTFT with Pi 4 / buster

Tags: pi-4, pitft, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I've gotten the PiTFT 2.8" capacitive [touchscreen](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install-2) to display the console on my Pi 4, using the instructions at that link. However, I can't get it to mirror the HDMI output. I used the buster lite (8/24/20) version of Raspberry Pi OS.

Is it compatible with that OS? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you see the note **The last known for-sure tested-and-working version is August 24, 2020** ?  That's the first thing I would check.  Without knowing the exact steps you did it's going to be a struggle but you should run the FBCP setup for your screen.  I take it you have an official Adafruit screen not a copy???  Do you get any errors or output at all?  Please expand your question to give steps you took (not supposed to take) OS details and program messages .

Comment: @Andyroo Yes that is the version I'm using. I ordered directly from Adafruit. No, no error messages, so I had nothing to add. The only thing I did that wasn't in the instructions was to install `pip3`. After that didn't work, i installed `lightdm` to allow it to boot into graphical, but still no dice.

Comment: Which FBCP setup are you referring to?

Comment: Pip3 is an installer and would have nothing to do with the display working or not - only if you can load the correct programs or not.  By version - do you mean display or Operating System or both?  If Operating System - did you run an `apt update` before trying the screen (doing so may invalidate the Adafruit instructions.  The FBCP is the actual trigger for the mirroring (it stands for FrameBuffer Copy) - without doing this you will never get the mirroring working.

Comment: @andy Yes, I know what pip is for. You asked for everything that wasn't in the instructions. I am using that version of the OS. I don't recall if I ran `apt update`. Is there a specific issue you have in mind there.

Comment: I meant did you mean the FBCP setup in the link? Because I did that, or did you have another step?

Comment: The one in the instructions.  Why lightdm - the Adafruit software is designed for Raspberry Pi OS - I would start from a clean install, DO NOT update OS, then follow the Instructions - copy paste all input out to here.

Comment: @Andyroo It seemed that some combination of `xutils` and `raspberry-pi-mods` were what was missing.